# Possible to collapse just comment sections?

Tags: visual-studio

I don't suppose there is a shortcut or an extension that makes it easy to collapse all the comment sections above methods without collapsing the methods? (bonus if it doesn't collapse comments inside the method, but okay if it does)

Comment: You can try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.CollapseComments